# codeigniter upload config

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to specify more than one configuration in config/upload.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it's not posible to do it, the manual says:

> **Setting preferences in a config file**
>
> If you prefer not to set preferences
>   using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file.
>   Simply create a new file called the
>   upload.php, add the $config array in
>   that file. Then save the file in:
>   config/upload.php and it will be used
>   automatically. You will NOT need to
>   use the $this->upload->initialize
>   function if you save your preferences
>   in a config file.

So you're adding to the $config array() without any key to auto-initialize. Probably will be better to make a config file and load it with your config params like:

```
$config['upload_1']['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
$config['upload_1']['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
$config['upload_1']['max_size'] = '100';
$config['upload_1']['max_width']  = '1024';
$config['upload_1']['max_height']  = '768';
```

And loading later in your Controller with:

```
$this->load->config('upload_vals', TRUE);

$upload_vals = $this->config->item('upload_1');

$this->load->library('upload', $upload_vals);
```

Wish it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way.

`application/config/upload.php`

```
<?php  if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

$config = array(
    'member_photo' => array(
        'upload_path'   => './uploads/member_photos/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',
        'max_size'      => '0',
        'max_width'     => '0',
        'max_height'    => '0',
        'encrypt_name'  => true
    ),
    'pet_photo' => array(
        'upload_path'   => './uploads/pet_photos/',
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpeg|jpg|png',
        'max_size'      => '0',
        'max_width'     => '0',
        'max_height'    => '0',
        'encrypt_name'  => true
    ),
);
```

`application/libraries/MY_Upload.php`

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload
{

    function initialize($config = array())
    {
        // load config
        if(!empty($config['config']))
        {
            $CI =& get_instance();
            $CI->load->config('upload');
            $autoload_config = $CI->config->item($config['config']);

            if($autoload_config)
            {
                foreach($autoload_config as $key => $val)
                {
                    if(empty($config[$key]))
                    {
                        $config[$key] = $val;
                    }
                }
            }

            unset($config['config']);
        }

        parent::initialize($config);
    }

}
```

Then in your controller; any extra keys you define will override those in the config file:

`$this->load->library('upload', array('config' => 'member_photo'));`